# Boost low frequency sine wave to high frequency

Tags: analog, frequency

I have a 50 Hz sine wave, which I need to convert to 1 kHz synchronously without delay. Can anybody suggest a method to do so?

Answer (score 2):

> *Can anybody suggest a method to do so?*

The usual turn-to method is to use a [phase-locked loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) circuit. This doesn't do frequency multiplication but, can be modified quite easily: -

[image: ![enter image description here]

Modification: Use a VCO that is nominally centred at about 1 kHz and, use a frequency divider if 20 in the feedback loop: -

[image]

If your 1 kHz is also required to be a sinewave then you need to find a VCO that outputs a sinewave and, before feeding into the frequency divider, you need to use a comparator to convert the sinewave to a square wave: -

[image]

Comment: I want synchronous reflection of 50Hz transposed to 1KHz. When looked in scope, any instantaneous change in 50Hz signal in terms of phase shall reflect in 1kHz almost instantly without too much lag. Would that be possible?

Comment: It depends on what the disturbance is @gari